# Rounding BigDecimal with the setScale() method: unexpected result

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

To round a number I use the following code:

```
public static roundBd(BigDecimal bd){
  BigDecimal result1 = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  return result1;
}
```

- Input 1.50 --> Output 2
- Input 1.499 --> Output 1

The first result is ok for me, but the second is not what I expected.
Even for 1.499 I'd like to have in output 2. (In details: first I'd like to round 1.499 to 1.50 then to 1.5 and finally to 2)

But....

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.499");  // I'd like to round it to 2
BigDecimal result1 = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // result1 == 1.50
BigDecimal result2 = bd.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // result2 == 1.5
BigDecimal result3 = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // result3 == 1
```

Comment: From that rounding style 1.4444444445 would round up to 2. That's not what we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way rounding works. HALF_UP means that if a number is exactly in the middle between the 2 closest available values (depending on the scale), it will be rounded up. Anything else is rounded to the closest value.

Extract from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP):

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant

To get to the behaviour you require, you could round successively although I'm not sure **why** you want such a behaviour:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.499");  // I'd like to round it to 2
BigDecimal result1 = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // result1 == 1.50
BigDecimal result2 = result1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // result2 == 2
```

Comment: Assylias, you're right. But I need to round an Euro currency value. The rule says that 1.499 should be rounded to 1.50. Then if I want to round it to integer I should get 2.

Comment: @AndreaBorgogelliAvveduti Ok - then the example I give should do what you need. Or more precisely, you should round all your currency amounts to 2 decimal places and that's your "official" value. Then you use that value and do what you want / need, including rounding it to 0 decimal places if you wish.

Comment: My JUnit tests say that's the right solution for Euro rounding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This result is exactly what you *should* get; rounding each intermediate sacrifices precision, so it rounds directly to the correct number of digits.

If you really want the other behavior, you'll have to do something like

```
while(number.scale() > 0) {
  number.setScale(number.scale() - 1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

Comment: Louise, on second thoughts you're right, the previous code do what should do. But I need to round an Euro currency value. The rule says that 1.499 should be rounded to 1.50. Then if I want to round it to integer I should get 2.